# Why does map function return None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, decoding, nonetype

I'm trying to code another encrypter, I'm having problems with the decoding process.
I've read a lot of StackOverflow's questions about this argument, I alredy know that someone is going to mark this question as a duplicate but I'm writing this because I can't find a solution to my problem.
The encode function gives me this string

```
4697625275273471234347364527724769
```

That is the encoded message (it says 'Hello world!') and I have the 'Key' (randomly generated every time I start the program), that cointains the combiantions of numbers needed to decode the message.
Here is the key

```
12040512030417060213060413030716060915090216080313040713060215090916020217020419040215050918070812050414030615020715020512061602071404091407041805160407170516030919090718050315070618020719070218050812030317020918060815070817020816040318080414060914060414050419030818030513020419030517040912040218020918030616050313050413040319070618020617060518060314090616070612080615060613020912040413070619070918050217040512070813020816020513090812090218080715020317050217050313070419020717090712060814020816030518040317030616050915020215030516050518080314040619060815030816020613040518080817060913070312080316050717020714070212090915090812090517030916060218091905051608071904041303021209031606081707051209081908041302051808021602081202041508031708041204031608041504031708051307051908081405091809051207091408061805061806021306061902021805041706081902061303031606051803091309061202031504061702021206091402091604041906041709091609061506081908091707021604061604081309051508091905041903031903071202021705061409091205091803071409041505071204061709041909091209061409051309041707031207041709061704021804051907071703031707091605081907051506041308051305071407031708031607021902051802051705041209071909081709051804041804091403021503031507071208051307021507041806051404031904031903061208041607031204071609091904091809031807031206041308091907041908031809071704031807071909021209041509071304041804071309071707061603081305051606031304021208071908021407081803021807021406071808051602041502061903091205051508051206031803081802021503061602031403081403091909061409081703021606071504051609041409031504021308021509051905031206071605021206051507021408021402061907031502041705091504081308081207051902091704061603071503041202061605061303091507091408041906091608061609081504041706071205021405021603041303041305031607081403051703041406061304081306071308061307081602091207061203091403071503091202051607041308071506021407071803031305021309031805091203061906051406031304061704071207071706031508061206021709021404051403041508071704041203071403031306081705051709081708061706041207031909031309091507031708021404041704081702031404071307071203051409071
```

it's a bit long.

And now that I have the parameters you need to put them in the decoder

```py
input_text = input('Encrypted MSG\n> ')
key = input('Key\n> ')
alphabet = list(" qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890èéòç@à°#ù§[]+*,;.:-_<>£$₽%&()=?ì^/|!ėëęēêĖËĘĒÉÈÊūûüúŪÛÜÚÙīïįíìîĪÏĮÍÌÎºōøõœöôóŌØÕŒÖÓÒãåāáâäæÃÅĀªÀÁÂÄÆßẞÇñÑ¥¢∆¶×÷π√•`~©®™✓йцукенгшщзхфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ⌂☻‼‰╛┐└┴┬├─┼╞╟╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤▬╥╙╘╒╓╫╪┘┌¤█▄▌▐▀αΣσ░▒▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝¿þ¼½¾ⁿ⌠⌡≤≥±≡∩∞ΘΩð«»⌐¬¨↨↑↓→←↔₧☼♥♦♣♠♂♀♪◘○◙►◄▲▼Þ‘’“”„☭卐")

key = key.replace('0', '')
key = key.replace('1', ' ')
key = key.split()
key.insert(0,'1')

charmap = zip(key, alphabet)
_map = dict(charmap)
output_text = ''.join(str(_map.get(c)) for c in input_text)

print(f'Output\n> {output_text}')
```

The output [ACTUAL]

```
Encrypted MSG
> 4697625275273471234347364527724769
Key
> 12040512030417060213060413030716060915090216080313040713060215090916020217020419040215050918070812050414030615020715020512061602071404091407041805160407170516030919090718050315070618020719070218050812030317020918060815070817020816040318080414060914060414050419030818030513020419030517040912040218020918030616050313050413040319070618020617060518060314090616070612080615060613020912040413070619070918050217040512070813020816020513090812090218080715020317050217050313070419020717090712060814020816030518040317030616050915020215030516050518080314040619060815030816020613040518080817060913070312080316050717020714070212090915090812090517030916060218091905051608071904041303021209031606081707051209081908041302051808021602081202041508031708041204031608041504031708051307051908081405091809051207091408061805061806021306061902021805041706081902061303031606051803091309061202031504061702021206091402091604041906041709091609061506081908091707021604061604081309051508091905041903031903071202021705061409091205091803071409041505071204061709041909091209061409051309041707031207041709061704021804051907071703031707091605081907051506041308051305071407031708031607021902051802051705041209071909081709051804041804091403021503031507071208051307021507041806051404031904031903061208041607031204071609091904091809031807031206041308091907041908031809071704031807071909021209041509071304041804071309071707061603081305051606031304021208071908021407081803021807021406071808051602041502061903091205051508051206031803081802021503061602031403081403091909061409081703021606071504051609041409031504021308021509051905031206071605021206051507021408021402061907031502041705091504081308081207051902091704061603071503041202061605061303091507091408041906091608061609081504041706071205021405021603041303041305031607081403051703041406061304081306071308061307081602091207061203091403071503091202051607041308071506021407071803031305021309031805091203061906051406031304061704071207071706031508061206021709021404051403041508071704041203071403031306081705051709081708061706041207031909031309091507031708021404041704081702031404071307071203051409071
Output
> NoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNone NoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNone
```

The output [EXPECTED]

```
Encrypted MSG
> 4697625275273471234347364527724769
Key
> 12040512030417060213060413030716060915090216080313040713060215090916020217020419040215050918070812050414030615020715020512061602071404091407041805160407170516030919090718050315070618020719070218050812030317020918060815070817020816040318080414060914060414050419030818030513020419030517040912040218020918030616050313050413040319070618020617060518060314090616070612080615060613020912040413070619070918050217040512070813020816020513090812090218080715020317050217050313070419020717090712060814020816030518040317030616050915020215030516050518080314040619060815030816020613040518080817060913070312080316050717020714070212090915090812090517030916060218091905051608071904041303021209031606081707051209081908041302051808021602081202041508031708041204031608041504031708051307051908081405091809051207091408061805061806021306061902021805041706081902061303031606051803091309061202031504061702021206091402091604041906041709091609061506081908091707021604061604081309051508091905041903031903071202021705061409091205091803071409041505071204061709041909091209061409051309041707031207041709061704021804051907071703031707091605081907051506041308051305071407031708031607021902051802051705041209071909081709051804041804091403021503031507071208051307021507041806051404031904031903061208041607031204071609091904091809031807031206041308091907041908031809071704031807071909021209041509071304041804071309071707061603081305051606031304021208071908021407081803021807021406071808051602041502061903091205051508051206031803081802021503061602031403081403091909061409081703021606071504051609041409031504021308021509051905031206071605021206051507021408021402061907031502041705091504081308081207051902091704061603071503041202061605061303091507091408041906091608061609081504041706071205021405021603041303041305031607081403051703041406061304081306071308061307081602091207061203091403071503091202051607041308071506021407071803031305021309031805091203061906051406031304061704071207071706031508061206021709021404051403041508071704041203071403031306081705051709081708061706041207031909031309091507031708021404041704081702031404071307071203051409071
Output
> Hello world!
```

The debug that I made with Visual Studio Code show that the problem is the map function

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: The keys of _map are strings with usually two or more digits but you ask it for strings consisting of one digit.

Comment: @MichaelButscher that part of code I alredy used it in another encoders (perfectly working) so I don't think that is the problem

Comment: I'm very sure you used in a different way which may have worked but it doesn't work here in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read one by one digit on the Encrypted message.
So if you have a `4` on your encrypted message to find `4` on the map you need to have `141` on your key due to the processing you do on your key.

In your exemple you dont have `141` on your generated key thats why you get `None`.

I change the key to use
`12141512030417060213060413030716060915090216080313040713060215090916020217020419040215050918070812050414030615020715020512061602071404091407041805160407170516030919090718050315070618020719070218050812030317020918060815070817020816040318080414060914060414050419030818030513020419030517040912040218020918030616050313050413040319070618020617060518060314090616070612080615060613020912040413070619070918050217040512070813020816020513090812090218080715020317050217050313070419020717090712060814020816030518040317030616050915020215030516050518080314040619060815030816020613040518080817060913070312080316050717020714070212090915090812090517030916060218091905051608071904041303021209031606081707051209081908041302051808021602081202041508031708041204031608041504031708051307051908081405091809051207091408061805061806021306061902021805041706081902061303031606051803091309061202031504061702021206091402091604041906041709091609061506081908091707021604061604081309051508091905041903031903071202021705061409091205091803071409041505071204061709041909091209061409051309041707031207041709061704021804051907071703031707091605081907051506041308051305071407031708031607021902051802051705041209071909081709051804041804091403021503031507071208051307021507041806051404031904031903061208041607031204071609091904091809031807031206041308091907041908031809071704031807071909021209041509071304041804071309071707061603081305051606031304021208071908021407081803021807021406071808051602041502061903091205051508051206031803081802021503061602031403081403091909061409081703021606071504051609041409031504021308021509051905031206071605021206051507021408021402061907031502041705091504081308081207051902091704061603071503041202061605061303091507091408041906091608061609081504041706071205021405021603041303041305031607081403051703041406061304081306071308061307081602091207061203091403071503091202051607041308071506021407071803031305021309031805091203061906051406031304061704071207071706031508061206021709021404051403041508071704041203071403031306081705051709081708061706041207031909031309091507031708021404041704081702031404071307071203051409071`

It finds `w` for `4` which is the result intended.

Best regards

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the problem, but still I can't find a way to fix this right now. What do you suggets?

Comment: @user187624 The first thing i will verify is: is the encryption method is bijectiv ? the second thing will be to check: how the key are made and use.

Comment: I made the encoding and the decoding so I understand how the key work (0 is just to confuse peoples and the 1 is the space). The bijectiv I used it on my first encrypter, this one is based on multiple numbers and not only one (example: "45": "C")

Comment: @user187624 As you do a mapping between the key and the alphabet. what you can do is as you do for the key put 1 as space in the encrypted word to devide character code.